# WPF Expander - Can't see the internal controls in Visual Studio 2010 Design window

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, expander

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and in a WPF app I'm using an expander. The prob is that the GroupBox etc inside the Expander are hidden from view in the Design window.

Any ideas to have them show?

Thx!

Comment: I have the same problem right now.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is old post so Gregg might already have answer to this. But, I'd like post answer because this might help others who stumbled across this issue.

The reason for expander not expanded in design view of VS 10 is that it's styled with user defined style like this:

```
  <Expander Header="Layout"           
            IsExpanded="True" 
            Style="{StaticResource ExpanderStyle_Normal}"> 
  </Expander>
```

So, there are two solutions:

1. Either, remove the **Style** attribute.

or/better

1. Set the **Visibility to "Visible"** in contentpresenter of controltemplate of that style.

   < ContentPresenter Visibility="Visible" />

**Note:** Both workarounds are only meant for designing phase so when you're done with it, you need to revert back to the setting that's needed for the run-time.

Comment: Setting the contentpresenter visibility to visible has no effect.